# Javascript remove events

Tags: javascript

I have simple library  "library" with init and destroy methods.

In init function i have the similar code:

```
var items = document.querySelector('....);

items.forEach(item => item.addEventListener(function(item) {
    return library.onClick(item)
});
```

So I want on destroy to remove the event handlers.

Since I need the item as parameter i pass anonymous function on "addEventListener"

But If I do the same on removeEventListener the function is not the same so no events will be removed.

How is the best way to approach this without using bind.

Should I save reference to the functions  and the use them to remove the events?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to create a `Map` that maps the `item`s to their associated handlers - that way, given an `item`, you can `.get` the handler that was added to that element:

```
const handlersByItem = new Map(
  [...items].map(item => [item, library.onClick(item)])
);
items.forEach((item) => {
  // make sure to declare the event type
  item.addEventListener('click', handlersByItem.get(item));
});

// To remove:
items.forEach((item) => {
  item.removeEventListener('click', handlersByItem.get(item));
});
```

Alternatively, if suitable, you might use event delegation instead - rather than add a separate handler to every single element, you might add a *single* handler to the container, then check if the clicked `target` exists in the `Map` - if it does, call the associated function. That way, you only have a single handler to attach and detach from the DOM.